# Redirect stderr to variable without debugging info

Tags: bash

I want to save the stderr of this command to a variable.

```
printf "1\r" > /dev/cu.usbserial
```

The stderr is `-bash: /dev/cu.usbserial: Permission denied`.  Good.

But when I run this in a bash script , the variable is prepended by the script name and line number.  How can I stop this from happening, and get it to show the error only?  I don't want to parse it with sed, etc.

```
var="$(printf "1\r" 2>&1 > /dev/cu.usbserial)"
```

`$var` is now:

```
/Users/elliott/Dropbox/scripts/switch1.sh: line 4: /dev/cu.usbserial: Permission denied
```

Comment: On all the variations I tried, the line printed to `stderr` for your first example is `bash: /dev/cu.usbserial: Permission denied`. Are you OK with the `bash:` prefix, or did you find some way to avoid it?

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  I did not find a way to avoid that, but I would like to.

Comment: A simple test: `[[ ! -w /dev/cu.usbserial ]] && echo "file is not writable by you"`

Answer (score 0):

I can’t figure out how to get the shell
that’s interpreting a script to “forget” that it’s doing that,
or to suppress the script-related diagnostic information
from its error messages. 
However, while this context information is preserved through forks
(into subshells), it is not passed across execs (to *new* shell processes). 
So, at the cost of fork/execing a new shell process, you can do

```
var=$(sh -c 'printf "1\r" > /dev/cu.usbserial' 2>&1)
```

which sets `$var` to

```
sh: /dev/cu.usbserial: Permission denied
```

A feature of `sh -c` that sometimes confuses people
(especially when they use it in `find … -exec sh -c "…" {} ";"`)
is that additional command-line arguments
(after the `-c` and the command for the new shell to run)
are taken as command-line parameters for the new shell,
***starting with `$0`.***  And `$0` is treated as the shell/script name,
which is subsequently used by the new shell to prefix error messages. 
So,

```
sh -c 'echo "Mellow rhymes with $2, but nothing rhymes with $1."; printf "1\r" > /dev/cu.usbserial' \
                                    red orange yellow
```

(broken into two lines solely for readability) outputs

```
Mellow rhymes with yellow, but nothing rhymes with orange.
red: /dev/cu.usbserial: Permission denied
```

So, if you’re willing to resort to a kludgy hack to get the variable value
to start with something other than `sh:` or `bash:`, use

```
var=$(sh -c 'printf "1\r" > /dev/cu.usbserial' error 2>&1)
```

which sets `$var` to

```
error: /dev/cu.usbserial: Permission denied
```

(by making the shell think that *its name* is `error`).